# How to use dynamodb QueryRequest with not equal condition in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query all items from dynamodb using query request with a particular column value not equal to a given value. Sharing the code which i have tried

`

```
 var request = new QueryRequest
            {
                 TableName = myTable,
           
                KeyConditionExpression = "CustomerGuid <> : v_CustomerGuid",
                
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>                 
                {        
                    {":CustomerGuid", new AttributeValue { S = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}},
                   
                },

            };

            var response = await myTable.QueryAsync(request);
```

`
where CustomerGuid  is a partition key
But I am getting this error message: 'Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: <>'

Can someone help me to find a solution?

Comment: That is not a supported query, you simply cannot query data that way. Is CustomerGuid the partition key? What purpose would that query even have!? It would return every single item except one?

Comment: Hi @luk2302, basically I want to get all items except the one using query request. Otherwise, is there any way I can get all the items using QueryRequest?

Comment: Perform a Scan and then manually remove the one item or Scan + FilterExpression

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Query you must provide an equality operator for the partition key, i.e `PK = 123`

You want a not equal, which goes against the fundamentals of NoSQL. In order to meet your needs you would need to do a full table `Scan` and use a filter condition to exclude the partition key that you do not want.